# How to handle onResponse method by using Retrofit library?

Tags: android, android-studio, null, retrofit2, jsonresponse

I am using retrofit library.I have created a class in which i am getting the value of particular id from other class, and i want to fetch particular list of that id but in the `onResponse()` method am getting an error. i checked in the postman in json format the list is fetching......but not here!

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<MailChimpEmailResponse> {

    public String idReceived;
    List<MailChimpEmailResponseSecond> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Call<MailChimpEmailResponse> call = MailChimpAPIClient.getClient().fetchMembers(idReceived,"efb918ee88a3a8a77-us15" );
        call.enqueue(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MailChimpEmailResponse> call, Response<MailChimpEmailResponse> response) {
    Log.d("ashu", "null response");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        idReceived = intent.getStringExtra("id_value");
        Log.d("ashu", "id received is: " + idReceived);

        MailChimpEmailResponse listResponse = response.body();

        for (MailChimpEmailResponseSecond list : listResponse.emailLists) {

            Log.d("ashu", list.getEmailListName());
            this.emailList = listResponse.emailLists;

        }

        recyclerViewSecond = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_second);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerViewSecond.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        EmailAdapter adapter = new EmailAdapter(this.emailList);
        recyclerViewSecond.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MailChimpEmailResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

my api class:

```
public interface MailChimpApi {


    @GET("lists")
    public Call<MailChimpListResponse> fetchLists(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("offset") int offset, @Query("count") int count);


    @GET("lists/{list_id}/members")
   public Call<MailChimpEmailResponse> fetchMembers(@Path("list_id") String listId,@Query("apikey") String apikey);
}
```

my json:

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "04d80020e78edd86a79eda",
      "email_address": "ashuingh.02046547@gmail.com",
      "unique_email_id": "784c772918",
      "email_type": "html",
      "status": "subscribed",
      "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": "Ashsdjssh",
        "LNAME": "kudjskjar"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following line should be in onCreate method instead of onResponse,

```
idReceived = intent.getStringExtra("id_value");
```